# Declare variable conditionally in LESS css

Tags: css, less

I currently have two Views that are using the same layout. However, they differ from each other in the following aspect:

View Foo:

```
<div class="MajorSection" id="foo">
</div>
```

View Bar:

```
<div class="MajorSection" id="bar">
</div>
```

And I want to declare `@labelWidth` differently between these two classes in one .less file so that I don't need to repeat myself with the following code.

```
.MajorSection {
    @labelWidth: 10em;

    .editor-label {
        width: @labelWidth;
    }

    input, textarea {
        width: (@editorWidth)-(.5em); //border & padding
    }
}
```

In View Foo I want `@labelWidth` to be `10em`, and in Bar I want it to be `20em`. Is there anyway to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the simplest method to achieve this is to define "depended" styles via [parametric mixin](http://lesscss.org/features/#mixins-parametric-feature), e.g.:

```css
.MajorSection {

    #foo& {
        .labelStyles(10em);
    }

    #bar& {
        .labelStyles(20em);
    }

    .labelStyles(@width) {
        .editor-label {
            width: @width;
        }
    }

    input, textarea {
        width: (@editorWidth - .5em); // border & padding
    }
}
```

CSS output:

```css
#foo.MajorSection .editor-label {
  width: 10em;
}
#bar.MajorSection .editor-label {
  width: 20em;
}
.MajorSection input,
.MajorSection textarea {
  width: ...;
}
```